# PREVENTING USING STOLEN CREDIT CARDS

Tags: php, payment, authorize.net, magento2.4.3, credit-card

Is there any way to prevent stolen credit cards on my website Magento 2.4.

I use authorize.net for cards payment, I had received a $400 payment for my products to ship in the USA.
But after I shipped the products I received an email from authorize.net that the cardholder has asked for a refund because they didn't authorize that transaction. Mean some else have used their card. After some investigation, I came to know that the person had used that card from Brazile and submitted a shipping address in the USA because I only ship in UK USA, and Canada.

So I lost my product and money. I want prevent that is there a way to do that?

looking for help

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answer is too late. We see things like that from time to time & when the business was just starting out we got burned on a couple. Authorize.net does a pretty good job of filtering  out the worst. The best answer I know of is not technical. Some orders just look funny: A successful capture shortly after a declined payment, gmail address with no recognizability & numbers in them, shipping address with unit numbers - they can often be a freight forwarder (stay away from freight forwarders) when we looked deeper into one such freight forwarder / stolen credit cards / ship the parcel over seas, it seemed like that was their whole business model. If anything doesn't add up, we look at Google street view for that address. It can be time consuming, but giving stuff to criminals is no fun